# How to extract dominant color from CIAreaHistogram?

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiimage, core-image, ciimage

I am looking to analyze the most dominant color in a UIImage on iOS (color present in the most pixels) and I stumbled upon Core Image's filter based API, particularly CIAreaHistogram.

It seems like this filter could probably help me but I am struggling to understand the API. Firstly it says the output of the filter is a one-dimensional image which is the length of your input-bins and one pixel in height. How do I read this data? I basically want to figure out the color-value with the highest frequency so I am expecting the data to contain some kind of frequency count for each color, its not clear to me how this one-dimensional image would represent that because it does not really explain the data I can expect inside this 1-d image. And if its truly a histogram why would it not return a data-structure representing that like a dictionary

Second, in the API it asks for a number of bins? What should that input be? If I want an exact analysis would the input bin parameter be the color-space of my image? What does making the bin value smaller do, I would imagine it just approximates nearby colors via Euclidean distance to the nearest bin. If this is the case will that not yield exact histogram results, why would anyone want to do that?

Any input on the above two questions from an API perspective would help me greatly

Comment: It looks like [CIKMeans](https://cifilter.io/CIKMeans) is coming in iOS 13

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CIAreaHistogram` returns an image where the reg, green, blue and alpha values of each of the pixels indicates the frequency of that tone in the image. You can render that image to an array of `UInt8` to look at the histogram data. There's also an undocumented `outputData` value:

```
let filter = CIFilter(
    name: "CIAreaHistogram",
    withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey: image])!
let histogramData = filter.valueForKey("outputData")
```

However, I've found `vImage` to be a better framework for working with histograms. First off, you need to create a `vImage` image format:

```
var format = vImage_CGImageFormat(
    bitsPerComponent: 8,
    bitsPerPixel: 32,
    colorSpace: nil,
    bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(
        rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue),
    version: 0,
    decode: nil,
    renderingIntent: .RenderingIntentDefault)
```

`vImage` works with image buffers that can be created from `CGImage` rather than `CIImage` instances (you can create one with the `createCGImage` method of `CIContext`. `vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage` will create an image buffer:

```
var inBuffer: vImage_Buffer = vImage_Buffer()

vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(
    &inBuffer,
    &format,
    nil,
    imageRef,
    UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))
```

Now to create arrays of `Uint` which will hold the histogram values for the four channels:

```
let red = [UInt](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0)
let green = [UInt](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0)
let blue = [UInt](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0)
let alpha = [UInt](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0)

let redPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(red)
let greenPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(green)
let bluePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(blue)
let alphaPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(alpha)

let rgba = [redPtr, greenPtr, bluePtr, alphaPtr]

let histogram = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>>(rgba)
```

The final step is to perform the calculation, which will populate the four arrays, and free the buffer's data:

```
vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888(&inBuffer, histogram, UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))

free(inBuffer.data)
```

A quick check of the `alpha` array of an opaque image should yield 255 zeros with the final value corresponding to the number of pixels in the image:

```
print(alpha) // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ... 409600]
```

A histogram won't give you the dominant color from a visual perspective: an image which is half yellow `{1,1,0}` and half black `{0,0,0}` will give the same results as an image which is half red `{1,0,0}` and held green `{0,1,0}`.

Hope this helps,

Simon

Comment: First off I would like to thank you for your answer! This has provided me great insights and I am thrilled someone was able to finally answer this. I'd like to accept your answer, just a few things I want to try tonight/tomorrow. Why have you found vImage to be a better framework? Is this strictly because of performance reasons or API ease of use?

Comment: Another Quick follow up would be is going through CIAreaHistogram then not the best way to find the dominant image color? Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I'd suggest vImage for histograms because they give the unadulterated pixel count per "bin" rather than a scaled 8 bit value. `CIAreaHistogram` seems best suited for use with `CIHistogramDisplayFilter` rather than working with the raw values. To the best of my knowledge, there's no way of writing a custom reduction filter in either Core Image Kernel Language or Metal Shading Language, so I don't think I have an answer to your second question.

Comment: Metal Shading language is pretty general on the compute side. You should be able to write most anything, including common reduction filters.

Comment: FYI thanks for the amazing answer, FYI It looks like [CIKMeans](https://cifilter.io/CIKMeans) is coming soon

Answer (score 6):

Ian Ollmann's idea of calculating the histogram just for the hue is really neat and can be done with a simple color kernel. This kernel returns a monochrome image of just the hue of an image (based on [this original work](https://gist.github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/114c1653de9e3da6e1e3))

```
let shaderString = "kernel vec4 kernelFunc(__sample c)" +
"{" +
"    vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);" +
"    vec4 p = mix(vec4(c.bg, K.wz), vec4(c.gb, K.xy), step(c.b, c.g));" +
"    vec4 q = mix(vec4(p.xyw, c.r), vec4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));" +

"    float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);" +
"    float e = 1.0e-10;" +
"    vec3 hsv = vec3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);" +
"    return vec4(vec3(hsv.r), 1.0);" +
"}"

let colorKernel = CIColorKernel(string: shaderString)
```

If I get the hue of an image of a blue sky, the resulting histogram looks like this:

[image: blue sky histogram]

...while a warm sunset gives a histogram like this:

[image]

So, that looks like a good technique to get the dominant hue of an image.

Simon

Comment: Thanks!  Amazing stuff.  PS looks like [CIKMeans](https://cifilter.io/CIKMeans) is in iOS 13

Answer (score 1):

One problem with the histogram approach is that you lose correlation between the color channels.  That is, half your image could be magenta and half yellow. You will find a red histogram that is all in the 1.0 bin, but the blue and green bins would be evenly split between 0.0 and 1.0 with nothing in between. Even though you can be quite sure that red is bright, you won't be able to say much about what the blue and green component should be for the "predominant color"

You could use a 3D histogram with 2**(8+8+8) bins, but this is quite large and you will find the signal is quite sparse. By happenstance three pixels might land in one bin and have no two the same elsewhere, even though many users could tell you that there is a predominant color and it has nothing to do with that pixel.

You could make the 3D histogram a lot lower resolution and have (for example) just 16 bins per color channel. It is much more likely that bins will have a statistically meaningful population count this way. This should give you a starting point to find a mean for a local population of pixels in that bin.  If each bin had a count and a {R,G,B} sum, then you could quickly find the mean color for pixels in that bin once you had identified the most popular bins.  This method is still subject to some influence from the histogram grid. You will be more likely to identify colors in the middle of a grid cell than at the edges. Populations may span multiple grid cells. Something like kmeans might be another method.

If you just want predominant hue, then conversion to a color space like HSV followed by a histogram of hue would work.

I'm not aware of any filters in vImage, CI or MetalPerformanceShaders to do these things for you. You can certainly write code in either the CPU or Metal to do it without a lot of trouble.