# optimized bubbleSort in dart

Tags: algorithm, dart, sorting, bubble-sort

so i have a task that made me do a bubblesort and I did this :

```
    bubbleSort(List<int> list) {
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list.length - 1; j++) {
      if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) {
        int num = list[j];
        list[j] = list[j + 1];
        list[j + 1] = num;
      }
    }
  }
  print(list);
}

void main() {
  List<int> list = [2, 5, 3, 15, 20, 5, 2, 7, 9];
  bubbleSort(list);
}
```

and now it want me to make an optimized bubbleSort how is that in Dart ?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"? If you change, well, almost anything, it's no longer bubblesort. (Which is a good thing, because bubblesort isn't *great*.)

Comment: Maybe his professor means "compile it with -O2 on the command line" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by optimized you mean it stops on ordered array than:

```cpp
bubbleSort(List<int> list) { int i,j,e;
  for (e=1,i=0; (i < list.length)&&(e); i++) {
    for (e=0,j=0; j < list.length - 1; j++) {
      if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) { e=1;
        int num = list[j];
        list[j] = list[j + 1];
        list[j + 1] = num;
      }
    }
  }
  print(list);
}

void main() {
  List<int> list = [2, 5, 3, 15, 20, 5, 2, 7, 9];
  bubbleSort(list);
}
```

I simply added `e` which is set on any swap which means once you iterate inner loop without swap the sorting stops..

This is still `O(n^2)` however much much faster on semi sorted data (in same direction)...

Another option to optimize this is to detect how much the array is sorted and if in asc or desc order. Once reverse order (in respect to used sort) is detected reverse the array before using bubble...

for the detection you can do something like this:

```cpp
for (e=0,i=1;i<list.length;i++) 
 if (list[i]>list[i-1]) e++; 
  else e--;
```

now the more positive `e` is the more asc sorted the array is and the more negative the more desc sorted the array is...

so you can add for example (for asc sorting):

```cpp
if (e<-list.length/4) // for asc sorting
//if (e>+list.length/4) // for desc sorting
 for (i=0,j=list.length-1;i<j;i++,j--) 
    {
    int num = list[i];
    list[i] = list[j];
    list[j] = num;
    }
```

and only now use bubble ...

Comment: IMO, the variable `e` should be declared inside the main loop.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I do not code in dart so I was afraid of some kind of syntax error ... feel free to repair

Comment: To the OP: in the worst case, this version (first in the post) is slower because it is doing an extra test.

Comment: But you know how to declare inside a block... In any case, the initialization e=1 seems superfluous.

Comment: @YvesDaoust My experience is that the first version is on average much faster can even beat quick sort on small arrays ... its slower only on almost sorted array in reverse direction which is dealt with the reversal. The extra if is not inside inner loop so its not a big deal as there is brunch already anyway. Yes you right the `e=1` init is just to feel safer and to avoid compiler warning...

Comment: however the quick sort wins with increasing `n` pretty quickly for example see [time comparison for `n=1024` data size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36932606/2521214)

Comment: I don't deny that. But in the worst case, this variant is *always* slower than that of the OP. You have a similar phenomenon with binary search with a test for early termination in case the key is found: if the key is not there, this variant is slower.